# Difference between the last and the first item of a criteria in a list

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet

```
          A                            B                    C         D     
1         Product ID                Time of Event
2         27152                01.04.2017  08:45:00       27152    70 Min.
3         27152                01.04.2017  09:00:00       29297    108 Min.
4         27152                01.04.2017  09:55:00       28802    28 Min.
5         29297                02.04.2017  11:02:00
6         29297                02.04.2017  12:50:00
7         28802                18.04.2017  11:48:00
8         28802                18.04.2017  12:00:00  
9         28802                18.04.2017  12:13:00
10        28802                18.04.2017  12:16:00
```

In **Column A** you can find different Product IDs.
In **Column B** the time when an event happens in the Product ID.
Each event is listed in the table; therefore, a ProductID can appear
several times in Column A.

In **Column D** I want to show now the difference in minutes between
the **first** and the **last** event which happens in a product ID.

```
D2 = 9:55:00 - 8:45:00 = 70 Min.
D3 = 12:50:00 - 11:02:00 = 108 Min.
D4 = 12:16:00 - 11:48:00 = 28 Min.
```

Therefore, I would need something like a *DIFFERENCE-IF-Formula*.
One of my ideas so far was going by the LARGE and SMALL function.

```
=LARGE(B2:B4;1)-SMALL(B2:B4;1)
```

However, this way I would have to find each array (B2:B4, B5:B6, B7:B10) seperatly; therefore, I would prefer to have the productID as a criteria in the formula.

**Summarized:**
Do you have any idea how I could calculate the difference in minutes between the **last** and the **first** event of a certain ProdcutID in the list?

*I would prefer to avoid any kind of array formula.*

Comment: So the entries in the Time of Event column are properly-recognised date/time values in your version of Excel? In mine, dates with the period (.) as separator are treated as text, not proper dates. Can you clarify? If you're not sure, test them with the ISNUMBER function, e.g. =ISNUMBER(B2) should return TRUE if the entry in that cell is a properly-recognised (i.e. numeric) date/time value.

Comment: Hi XOR LX, if I put ISNUMBER it returns TRUE. I am using a German Excel Version 2010.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will post an answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=ROUND(MMULT(AGGREGATE({14,15},6,B$2:B$10/(A$2:A$10=C2),1),{1;-1})*1440,1)&" Min"`

and copied down.

I've a feeling the separators for horizontal and vertical arrays in German versions of Excel are the period (.) and semicolon (;) respectively, so I believe you'll need:

`=RUNDEN(MMULT(AGGREGAT({14.15};6;B$2:B$10/(A$2:A$10=C2);1);{1;-1})*1440;1)&" Min"`

though please let me know if that doesn't give the required results.

Regards

Comment: I should add that you need Excel 2010 or later for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

With some conditions,
1. assuming that you convert column B into 2 columns
2. times is in ascending order

```
     A            B            C
Product ID  Time of Event    TIMES      
27152         01.04.2017    8:45:00
27152         01.04.2017    9:00:00
27152         01.04.2017    9:55:00
29297         02.04.2017    11:02:00
29297         02.04.2017    12:50:00
28802         18.04.2017    11:48:00
28802         18.04.2017    12:00:00
28802         18.04.2017    12:13:00
28802         18.04.2017    12:16:00
```

This will work without using array

```
=(INDEX($C$2:$C$10,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW($A$2:$A$10)*(D2=$A$2:$A$10))-1))-INDEX($C$2:$C$10,MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$10,0)))*1440
```

Convert time into minutes

```
=(time*1440)
```

Look for first matching value

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$10,MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$10,0))
```

Look for last matching value

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$10,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW($A$2:$A$10)*(D2=$A$2:$A$10))-1)
```

**NOTE** If last value is SMALLER then first value, you will receive an error.